# VB Script SaveAs not saving format change

Tags: vbscript

I have a vbscript that I want to use to format a file that i export using a stored procedure in SQL. I will eventually use a batch to schedule this so it is automatic. I am trying to get the script to work first before finishing it off.

The problem I am having is that the changes aren't saving in my new file.

So far I have;

```
Dim objXL
Dim wb
Dim ws

Set objXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objXL.Visible = False
objXL.DisplayAlerts = False

Set wb = objXL.Workbooks.Open("H:\Pricing.xls")
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Pricing")

ws.Rows(1).Font.Bold=True
wb.SaveAs("H:\Pricing2.xls")

objXL.Quit
```

If i change objXL.Visible to True i can see that the first row does indeed turn bold before creating the new file and closing. However when i open Pricing2.xls manually, the row is no longer bold.

Any ideas why the format changes are not sticking?

Cheers

Comment: Is Excel really closing? When I've had problems like this, it was because the spreadsheet was already open by an earlier process from when a script crashed, for example.

Comment: I was having a similar issue before and it would create a new process each time without closing. However that is not the case anymore unfortunately :( - Just confirmed with task manger processes.

Comment: I've rolled back your edits with the solution; that's not how StackOverflow works. It's fine to post a solution to your problem here if you find one and want to share it, but you need to do so by posting an actual answer, not by editing the question. This is a question and answer site, not a "post my problem and solution" blog. There's more info in [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file format of the SQL generated file was causing my issue, declaring the fileformat on SaveAs solved the issue;

```
wb.SaveAs "H:\Pricing2.xls", FileFormat -4143
```